# Which hook can I use for a Drupal webform Post to a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms

I have a webform with some options and fields. When user submit the form i receive an email.

I want to hook right before(or after) drupal send the email and populate my Google  Spreadsheet so i can review from my Google Drive account.(And send the email as normal)

I have make the connection with a custom php file. I don't know what hook i can use.

Comment: hook_webform_submission_presave? http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7

Comment: I will try it asap!

Comment: @Neograph734 Can you make it as an Answer so i can select it ? Thank you again!!!!

Comment: I've added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook you need is `hook_webform_submission_presave($node, $submission)` that, according to the [documentation](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7) allows to modify a Webform submission, prior to saving it in the database.

So all values should be available there.